# How to properly test Universal links?

Tags: nsurlsession, ios-universal-links

I have several questions about Universal links implementation. I read a lot of information from SO/other sources but questions are remain.

At first, I want to say that I correctly configured project (added entitlements, added callback to AppDelegate) and correctly configured AASA with my team id/bundle id (I have a working example from another service).

**Quiestion #1.**

Is root directory still working location for `apple-app-site-association`  (further AASA) file? How I can check it with SWCD (what kind of message should be)? I found next problem: our site based on WordPress and it's a bit problematic (I'm not familiar with WordPress - only have words of my colleague) to add this file to `.well-known` directory. So my colleague just added AASA directly to the root directory. But, universal links are not working. I found only one meaningful message from device's logs: (loading AASA file failed) -

```
Request for '<private>' denied due to HTTP status 404 on route .wk for task AASA-1D53AE3E-9261-413F-B384-20D1DC57B81A { domain: ch….dk?mode=developer, bytes: 0, route: .wk }
```

Seems like SWCD tries to load a file from non-existing `.well-known` directory (because of 404 error), but I don't understand is it tries to load a file from root directory.

Also, I tried to run my site through  [validator](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator) - and it failed. From [this source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1919/_index.html) - there is no difference using root directory or `.well-known` directory - they both should work.

OK, let's assume this validator is wrong.

**Question #2.**

Is it possible to 100% find where the problem exactly? (iOS or backend/site side)

It is not clear how exactly https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool works. For example, I checked facebook.com.

`Results: Link to Application is passed. Universal = true.`

I checked instagram.com.

`Results: Link to Application - no exact answer. Universal = false.`

The results are quite ambiguous.

Anyway, both http://instagam.com/apple-app-site-association and http://facebook.com/apple-app-site-association return valid file and I'm sure universal links are working through their iOS applications.

**Question #3.**

I checked several AASA files in Postman. I noticed that my AASA file does not contain `content-type` header. Facebook, Instagram and others contain this header for their AASA files. They all have different values, but they **return in responses**. Can be it an issue?

**Question #4.**

Any other ideas? I will be appreciated. I think my issue that iOS system does not recognize AASA file from my site. But I don't have ideas how to fix it now.

Answer (score 5):

Better place "apple-app-site-association" file in ".well-known" folder.

Branch.io and Apple Validator are useless. Better just to validate json.

Use iOS 13 version of "apple-app-site-association" file.

```
   {
      "applinks": {
          "apps": [],
          "details": [
            {
              "appID": "ABC1234567.co.app.prod",
              "paths": ["/first/*", "/second/*"]
            },
            {
              "appID": "ABC1234567.com.app.dev",
              "paths": ["/first/*", "/second/*"]
            }
          ]
      }
    }
```

Apple CDN caches "apple-app-site-association" file data.
Use developer mode when testing.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<array>
    <string>applinks:example.com?mode=developer</string>
</array>
```

In developer mode app fetches "apple-app-site-association" file data directly from your site.

To test on device in developer mode enable associated domains in settings->development...

Uploaded "apple-app-site-association" file should be with header `content-type=application/json.`

Don't forget to disable developer mode when finish testing.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for you answer! But currently, my main suggestion why it's not working - wrong AASA location file. I requested to move it to .well-known directory because we need it for Android app as well. Will return later with news